# word-wrap:break-word is not working with iText 2.1.7

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext

I am using **Java** & **Itext2.1.7** for generating **pdf** and I have written the following **HTML**. But it is not breaking words when they are too long.

```
String td ="<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" style=\"table-layout: fixed;word-wrap:break-word;white-space: normal;\"><b>"
                    + verylongwordverylongwordverylongword + ":</b></td>"
```

Can someone help me achieving this?

Comment: break-word is a css3 attribute. Does iText fully support css3 when converting from html, it is hard to tell as the documents are closed

Comment: Thanks @Woody, Due to your comment I actually got to know that IText does not support break-word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Itext 2.7.1** does not support **word-wrap : break-word** property. Following is the link for that.

http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html

So I have manually break the words according to the no of columns of the Table and by taking assumption of maximum letters around 60-65.Following is the code for that.

```
public String getBrokenWordsForPdfGeneration(String longString, int cutIndex){
       StringBuffer mainStringBuffer = new StringBuffer(longString);
       String returnString = "";
       while(mainStringBuffer != null && mainString.length()>0 &&                              
mainString.subString(0,mainString.length()>cutIndex?cutIndex:mainString.length()) != null){ 
          if(mainStrig.subString(0,mainString.length()>cutIndex:mainString.length()).trim().contains(" ")){
               returnString += mainStrig.subString(0,mainString.length()>cutIndex:mainString.length()).trim();
               mainStringBuffer.delete(0,mainString.length()>cutIndex:mainString.length());
          }else{
              returnString += mainStrig.subString(0,mainString.length()>cutIndex:mainString.length()).trim()+ " ";
              mainStringBuffer.delete(0,mainString.length()>cutIndex:mainString.length());
          }
    }
    return returnString;
}
```